# FullCalendar unknown option 'dateClick'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a rails 6 application and added FullCalendar by following the [official docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6)(using yarn and webpacker)

When I run the server, the calendar displays correct and clicking on an event also works, but clicking on a date doesn't do anything. In the developer tools I get the message: Unknown option 'dateClick'.

My calendar.js looks like this:

```js
  import { Calendar } from "@fullcalendar/core";

  import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";

  import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";

  import listPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list";

  import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

  import bootstrapPlugin from "@fullcalendar/bootstrap";

  import nlLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/nl";

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

    const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        listPlugin,
        interactionPlugin,
        bootstrapPlugin
      ],
      themeSystem: "bootstrap",
      initialView: "dayGridMonth",
      eventClick(info) {
        console.log("Event clicked")
      },
      dateClick(info) {
        console.log("Date clicked")
      }
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```

When I copy the code from `node_modules/@fullcalendar/interaction/main.js` and paste it in a different file and import it from there it works.

Answer (score 4):

Problem was that `@fullcalendar/core` was installed with version 5.1.0 and `@fullcalendar/interaction` was installed with version 5.2.0.

Upgrading `@fullcalendar/core` to 5.2.0 solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, installing all plugins in the same version solved the issue; 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 eventClick: function(info) {
```

and

```
 dateClick: function(info) {
```

instead of

```
eventClick(info) {
...
dateClick(info) {
```

Comment: That doesn't makes any difference, and like I said the eventClick does work. Only dateClick doesn't.

Comment: You are right. Doesen't matter wheter dateClick(info) or dateClick: function(info).

Comment: I tried with your code starting from eventClick: no Problems found so far. Maybe a missing plugin?

Comment: I added the interaction plugin with `yarn add @fullcalendar/interaction` and I can see it is inside the node_modules folder.

Comment: Sorry to butt in. I don't know anything about Ruby. I thought it might be a very small glitch in the code. I just tested with the "normal" implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If someone encountered this error when implementing the dateClick of FullCalendar. I solved this problem using the version of 5.6. All package must have the same version

```
npm install @fullcalendar/daygrid@5.6
npm install @fullcalendar/interaction@5.6
npm install @fullcalendar/vue@5.6
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30750367)